# Limit or disable Cloud Function logging

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to limit or disable logging from Cloud Function in GCP?
I have a Cloud Function, written in Ruby and it is logging almost all information to logs.

I couldn't find any option during set up of the Cloud Function, maybe in code using function framework?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The answer from @sandeep-vokkareni is correct for disabling logging, However, do not do that. Logging is vital for managing cloud resources. Instead, improve your application to support logging levels. Then enable the level of information you need so that extra information is not logged. Review **levels**: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

Comment: @sfazovany "Posted an asnwer, Is it helpful?"